# How to hide keyboard and select text programmatically at the same time in UITextview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview

I have following code in -(void)viewDidLoad

```
[txtView becomeFirstResponder];
[txtView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
```

That is, I want to programmatically select text in my UITextView.
At the same time, I don't want the keyboard show up. 
I tried add following code -

```
[txtView setEditable:NO];
```

or

```
[txtView resignFirstResponder];
```

Although they make keyboard hide away, however either way also make the text selection disappear.

To sum up, I want to select text programmatically and disable keyboard at the same time.
I think it's possible, because when I have [txtView setEditable:NO]; I can still touch on screen to select text.
The question is only that I don't know how to do that all programmatically.
Can someone help me?

Comment: And may I ask as to why you wish to violate the HIG?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs on `-resignFirstResponder`:

> Subclasses can override this method to update state or perform some
>   action such as unhighlighting the selection, or to return NO, refusing
>   to relinquish first responder status. If you override this method, you
>   must call super (the superclass implementation) at some point in your
>   code.

You'll need to subclass UITextView and override the `-resignFirstResponder` method, possibly like this:

```
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
    [self setEditable:NO];
    [self setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
    return YES;

}
```

Theoretically, this should work, but the nitty-gritty inside resignFirstResponder might not like it too much.

Answer (score 0):

you can use little delay for doing this. see this,

write this code in viewDidLoad

```
[txtView becomeFirstResponder];
[txtView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
[self performSelector:@selector(resignKeyBoard) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];
```

and

```
-(void)resignKeyBoard
{
   [txtView resignFirstResponder]; 
}
```

Comment: thank you Ishu, but it's not what I want, the selection still disappear after delay.

Comment: @Nohappy, then you need NSAttributedString, fetch the content of UITextView and selected portion text must be change in some different color for showing selection.